# Pause for certain time in Sencha?

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch

I have an issue where a grid I'm creating appears *during* the slide animation instead of after. Because of this, I've decided to use a timer to wait 1 second before it creates the gridview. How do I go about doing this? setTimeout didn't do what I expected it to...

Comment: Can you post some of your code please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
    alert(Ext.getDom('myInputField').value.length);
});
// Wait 500ms before calling our function. If the user presses another key
// during that 500ms, it will be cancelled and we'll wait another 500ms.
Ext.get('myInputField').on('keypress', function(){
    task.delay(500);
});
```

See [Sencha Touch API reference](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.util.DelayedTask)